Why is a Sitefinity widget considering the URL path
I have created a Widget like this:
[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "MyFirstWidget", Title = "My First Widget", SectionName = "Custom")]
public class MyFirstWidgetController : Controller, IPersonalizable
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyFirstWidgetModel();
        model.Message = this.Message;
        return View("Index", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View("Test", model);
    }   

    public string Message { get; set; }  
}

Index.cshtml
@model Learn_SF.Mvc.Models.MyFirstWidgetModel
<div>
    @Model.Message
</div>

Test.cshtml
<div>
    This is test
</div>

Added this to 2 pages - Home & Test. The Test page is under Home. Then assigned the respective Message values "Content from home page" & "Content for test page",



URL
Content Displayed




1. /home
Content for home page. /as expected/


2. /home/test
404 error. /This is before I created the Test page. So as expected./


3. /home/test
Content for test page. /This is after I created the Test page. So as expected/


4. /home/test/test
This is test.



For #4, it seems that the last fragment in URL is considered as Controller method. But somehow the same logic did not apply for #2.
I'm confused as why is the widget considering URL to check for backend methods. I was expecting that it would only be the Index method for every widget as default. But if this is the default behavior, how do we know if the system is looking for a page or a controller method if they have the same name.
Using Sitefinity 14.1.

Did you uncheck Allow Parameter Validation property from the Title and Properties of the Home page?
Normally, #2 should also work, given that checkbox is checked.
To make #2 work (without the need to create a Test page under Home), you can try adding this line at the start of the Test action:
public ActionResult Test()
{
        RouteHelper.SetUrlParametersResolved(true);

        return View("Test", model);
}   

It is telling Sitefinity routing - hey, I can handle this request, do not throw 404.

If #2 works, that adds to my confusion. What is the default behavior and shouldn't the widget be only triggering Index() irrespective of the URL path.

No, any GET action method would be mapped to a url, not just the Index
